# Admin user roles/permissions

Tags: admin, user-roles

I have a user who I would like to able to publish new posts/pages, but I don't want them to have access to users. I may want to let them have access to specific plugins, but not others.

Is there a plugin for this? A built-in method I'm not seeing?

I'm a little lost on how to go about managing permissions.

Comment: Greg, can you update your question with the relevant plugins and pages you want to access please?

Answer (score 1):

The ["Contributor" role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor) has very little access to anything on the back end but can created posts.

> - delete_posts
> - edit_posts
> - read
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor

For comparison, an ordinary "Subscriber" has the last of the three, so "Contributor" has only two extra capabilities.

I am not quite sure what "access to specific plugins" means exactly but I am nearly certain that you can't do that with Core WordPress. If you were more specific about what you want I might be able to do better.

Comment: I appreciate the response. As far as 'access to specific plugins' I am referring to the pages the plugins create. For instance, I would like to give someone access to the admin pages of a specific plugin without making them admin.

Comment: Those pages are linked to specific capabilities, so if we knew the plugin we could probably show you what code to change.  That said, if you hack a plugin, you're opening up a entirely new set of problems, the most prominent being that you won't be able to update the plugin without the changes being overwritten.

Comment: Because of the way plugin pages are registered this might be tricky. I have never tried to hijack plugin admin page capabilities but I will take a shot later if I can get the time. @AndrewBartel is correct that hacking the plugin would do it but also correct that that introduces a number of headaches.

Comment: You could potentially remove_menu_page() and then readd it on a super low priority hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) to change the menu option to only be available to a user with a certain capability. Then using the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) you can create custom capabilities and add them to the roles you want to access the plugins. Then go to the admin menu editor and change the Required Capability to your custom added capability. That should fix your problem.